# continuous real-valued function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous real-valued function in a circle $|z|\leq1$ and $|f|\leq1$. Prove that $| \oint_{|z|=1} f(z)dz |\leq4 $.

Any hint, please.

Comment: "From top to integral"? What does that mean?

Comment: My bad. I am not native speaker

Comment: You can’t do a contour integral on a ball!

Comment: Corrected the condition

Comment: Isn't $ \oint_{|z|=1} dz = 2 \pi$ ?

Comment: I dont the max of f

Comment: $\oint_{|z|=1} dz = 0$ by Cauchy (!) - or just parametrize

Comment: Anyway, it doesn't help me

Comment: Do you require $\oint_{|z|=1} f(z) \,\mathrm{d}z$ to be real? It does not have to be in general.

Comment: I made a change

Answer (score 3):

Let **real** $x,y$ (here we use the real nature of $f$ and by a slight abuse of notation we denote $f(e^{i\theta}) = f(\theta)$ on the unit circle) be $\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(\theta)\cos(\theta)d\theta$ and $\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(\theta)\sin(\theta)d\theta$ respectively; by parametrization, the problem reduces to showing that |$x+iy$| $\leq 4$, or that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq 4$; we can assume $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ not zero as there is nothing to prove then and let $\alpha$ s.t. $\cos(\alpha) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$,  $\sin(\alpha) = \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$.

Then $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ = 
$\int_{0}^{2\pi}{f(\theta)\cos(\theta)\cos(\alpha)d\theta + \int_{0}^{2\pi}f(\theta)\sin(\theta)\sin(\alpha)}d\theta$=$\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(\theta)\cos(\theta-\alpha)d\theta$ and by taking absolute values and using $|f(\theta)| \leq 1$, RHS is at most $\int_{0}^{2\pi} |\cos(\theta-\alpha)|d\theta$ = $4$, so we are done.

(by periodicity  $\int_{0}^{2\pi} |\cos(\theta-\alpha)|d\theta$ =  $\int_{0}^{2\pi} |\cos(\theta)|d\theta$ = $4\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos\theta d\theta = 4$)

Comment: Where are you using real-value of function?

Comment: Sorry, and why the last integral is exactly equal to 4?

Comment: And what does it mean RHS?

Comment: In the fact that $x,y$ are real.  RHS means right hand side

Comment: Note that it is enough for $f$ to be defined real, measurable and bounded on the unit circle only