# What is the meaning of "$\;\ll\;$", as in "$\;f\ll1\;$" and "$\;\int_{|z|=1}f\ll 4\;$"?

Tags: complex-analysis, notation, self-learning

I have some confusion in symbolic , my confusion marked in red colour given below

[image: mbol]

Comment: Much less than, or very small. (Maybe)

Comment: @UmbQbify-Key20- i think its  should be  $ <$   like this

Comment: that's simply less than. Example $2>1$ but $2>\!\!>10^{-12}$

Comment: I have seen $f\ll g$ written for $f=O(g)$ before, but I don't know if that's what the author means here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#History_(Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau,_Hardy,_and_Vinogradov_notations)

Comment: In the context of Banach lattices, $f \ll g \iff \;\exists\; c >0$ such that $cf \leq g.$

Comment: here it means that if $|f| \le1$ (continuous, real valued) then $|\int_{|z|=1}fdz| \le 4$; here is a proof https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3124800/continuous-real-valued-function/3125293#3125293